# Nestjs + postgresql +dto store jsonb gives must be a json string error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, dto, nestjs-typeorm

Currently having `nestjs` setup up with `postgresql` as database.
I know that `postgresql` columns can store `json`, so I am trying to play around with it but I keep on getting the error

```
{
    "message": [
        "content must be a json string"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "statusCode": 400
}
```

I wonder what's wrong with my setup.

My entities includes this column

```
  @Column('jsonb', { nullable: false, default: {} })
  content: IContent;
```

In my CreateUpdateDTO, I have the following.

```
  @IsJSON()
  content: IContent;
```

IContent is just an interface

```
export interface IContent {
  messages: string [];
  detail: string;
}
```

Then in postman I have this as raw json body

```
{
  "content": {
     "messages": ["testing", "testing", "123"],
     "detail": "some detail"
  }
}
```

Then I'd get that error of `"content must be a json string"`

Wonder where I setup wrong or missed something?

Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs:

> @IsJSON() Checks if the string is valid JSON.

However

```json
{
  "messages": ["testing", "testing", "123"],
  "detail": "some detail"
}
```

Is obviously not a `string` so the validation failure is expected. See [JSON Object Literals](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp#:%7E:text=JSON%20cannot%20be%20an%20object,it%20becomes%20a%20JavaScript%20object.)
[Here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1374#issuecomment-1353878705) you can find an example of how to use [@IsJSON()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator)

But think in your use case you don't need the decorator, your JSON payload should be accepted without any issues, and the content property will be automatically converted to JSON and stored in the jsonb column.

Comment: That do make sense but so I guess since I don't need any other decorators for this column...in DTO I'll leave it as `content: IContent;` ?

Comment: @Dora yes you can do that

Comment: Gonna mark this as the answer but ended up still need to add at least a decoration of `@IsNotEmpty()` else just `content: IContent` itself will send empty object to the db even though the object is not empty

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom validator for Json:

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from 'class-validator';

export function IsJsonObject(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: NonNullable<unknown>, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isJsonObject',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any) {
          if (typeof value === 'string') {
            try {
              const parsed = JSON.parse(value);
              // Ensure the parsed value is an object and not an array or null
              return parsed !== null && typeof parsed === 'object' && !Array.isArray(parsed);
            } catch (e) {
              return false;
            }
          } else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value)) {
            // Directly validate objects (but not arrays or null)
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

and call it like:

```
  @AutoMap()
  @IsOptional()
  @Field(() => GraphQLJSONObject, { nullable: true })
  @IsJsonObject({
    message: 'metadata must be a valid JSON object or string',
  })
  metadata?: Record<string, any>;
```